# Removal with quel

Tags: grammaire, anglais, comparaison-de-langues, pronoms-interrogatifs

The phrase *La question est posée de savoir quels sont les contenus scientifiques* translates to "The question arises as to what is the scientific content"

How come *savoir* seems to be removed from the translation?  What type of grammatical categorization is happening here that makes *savoir quels* go from "know what" to just "what".

When I remove *savoir* it gets translated to "The question is asked what are the scientific contents," - so is savoir even required here?  Is it used to keep the clause singular, couldn't you just write *quel est le* instead, to keep it singular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just one of those "formulas", or manner of speech that is not translated word for word between languages. It really means the same as "la question est, quels sont..." or "la question est: quels sont...". 
The English "One wants to know, what is ..." could be use as a translation that keeps savoir/know. 
In fact many modern French speakers will find the original sentence a bit archaic and long winded